# List as local and global variable and changing global list value after method call

Tags: c#, datagridview, scope, listbox

```
public Class Card
{
}
public partial class Form
{
    List<Card> list2 = new List<Card>();
}
public List<Card> insertInList(ref List<Card> list1)
{
   foreach(...)
   {
    list1.Add(instanceOfObject Card)
   }
return list2;
}
private void btn_click(...)
{
   insertInList(ref list2);
}
```

***Edit 1*** As this is my second edit, I would appreciate If somebody can tell me that I am using "ref" modifiers well in order to have list full of elements after calling insertInList() method?

**Edit 2** How would You change this example, but to have same list full of elements after insert method call, but If your list is defined in method insertInList?

**Edit3 (The Biggest Issue)** I have still problem, that I am getting 3 lists (same names as Namespace.Class) in ListBox while I am expecting only 1?

```
public List<Karta> ubaciUListu(ref List<Karta> Lista1)
{
        //List<Karta> Lista11 = new List<Karta>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            Karta k = new Karta(0,"","");
          // k.Id =(int)row.Cells[0].Value;
            k.Pojam =(string) row.Cells[1].Value;
            k.Opis = (string)row.Cells[2].Value;

            Lista1.Add(k);


        }
        return Lista1;
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    List<Karta> nova = new List<Karta>();
    public Form2(List<Karta> input)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        nova = input;
        if (nova.Count!=0)
        { 
        lstBox.DataSource = nova;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than snippets - ideally without any GUI involvement. (Console apps are much easier to provide as minimal examples.)

Comment: Use breakpoints at the end of your method and buttun click event and also form2 constructor and control the number of items in your list. Also, override .ToString() for your Karta class to get the correct result in listbox, Namespace.class value is because you havent override .ToString() method for the class.
PS: Your question is somehow confusing

Comment: Which list is part of which form object? Which click event is part of which form? Which method is part of which class? Why you need to use ref keyword if you have access to form level fields in all the methods of Form?

Comment: I can access but I cant store objects in list after method call(if list is defined outside of the method), so I am using ref modifier. I would get empty list in that case.